# Making a phone call in blocked mode

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am making an SOS application that, when pressing the power button three times, should make a call to a pre-defined number and send an SOS message to the specified numbers, the problem is that it sees that the power button is pressed and sends a message but does not make a call over the lock.

MyReceiver:

```
class MyReceiver(activity: Activity?) : BroadcastReceiver() {

   private var activity: Activity? = null
   var t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
   var t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
   var thread: Thread? = null
   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

       Log.v("onReceive", "Power button is pressed.")

       val a = countPowerOff + 1

       if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) {
           countPowerOff++
           if (countPowerOff == 1) t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
           if (countPowerOff == 3) t2 = System.currentTimeMillis()
       } else {
           if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {

               if (countPowerOff == 3) {
                   Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked to call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                       .show()
               }

               if (countPowerOff == 3 && t2 - t1 <= 5000) {
                   thread = Thread(Task())
                   thread!!.start()

               }
               if (countPowerOff == 3) {
                   countPowerOff = 0
               }
           }
       }
   }

   internal inner class Task : Runnable {
       override fun run() {
           (activity as MainActivity).callFragmentMethod()
       }
   }

   companion object {
       var countPowerOff = 0
       var starttime = 0
   }

   init {
       this.activity = activity
   }
}
```

Method for making a call and sending a message:

```
fun sendSos() {

        val manager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            sosMassage =
                "I need help, I'm at Latitude: ${currentLocation.latitude} and Longitude ${currentLocation.longitude} https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${currentLocation.latitude},${currentLocation.longitude}"
        }

        threadCall = Thread(callSOS())
        threadCall!!.start()

        threadMessage = Thread(sendSOS())
        threadMessage!!.start()

    }
internal inner class callSOS : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            checkForCallSmsPermission()
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL)
            val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
            val callPreferences = prefs.getString("call_preference", "1")
            if (callPreferences == "1") {
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:103"))
            } else {
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:${prefs.getString("contact_text_1", "103")}"))
            }
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
internal inner class sendSOS : Runnable {

        override fun run() {

            checkForSmsPermission()
            val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext())
            val sms = SmsManager.getDefault()
            val textPreferences = prefs.getString("text_preference", "1")
            val primaryContact = prefs.getString("contact_text_1", "0701217070")

            sms.sendTextMessage(
                primaryContact,
                null,
                sosMassage,
                null,
                null
            )
            if (textPreferences == "2") {
                for (i in 2..3) {
                    val contactNumber = prefs.getString("contact_text_$i", null)
                    if (contactNumber != null) {
                        sms.sendTextMessage(
                            contactNumber,
                            null,
                            sosMassage,
                            null,
                            null
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe explain what you've tried, or how you intend it to work

Comment: I'm a beginner, to do the work on top of other applications, but it did not help, so I wanted to ask those who know in which direction they are moving